# Docker compose why do i get "ERROR : page not found"?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have an error when running my docker compose up i get this :
`ERROR: page not found`

if i run with verbose i get this : in the end

```
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.30/images/service-statistics-image:1.0.0%0A0/json HTTP/1.1" 404 29
ERROR: compose.cli.errors.log_api_error: page not found
```

i search a solution online but no one seems to get this error.
Also all images i use in docker compose should be on my computer so it shouldn't need to pull anything

Please help.

Here are some precisions :
i run the docker compose from this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

/app/scripts/stop-services.sh

cd /app

hardwareVersion=$(docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" | grep "hardware" | cut -d' ' -f2)
paymentVersion=$(docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" | grep "payment" | cut -d' ' -f2)
hotfolderVersion=$(docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" | grep "hotfolder" | cut -d' ' -f2)
statisticsVersion=$(docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" | grep "statistics" | cut -d' ' -f2)
infosVersion=$(docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" | grep "infos" | cut -d' ' -f2)
receiptVersion=$(docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" | grep "receipt" | cut -d' ' -f2)
uiVersion=$(docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" | grep "service-ui" | cut -d' ' -f2)
telemetryVersion=$(docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" | grep "telemetry" | cut -d' ' -f2)

export hardwareVersion
export paymentVersion
export hotfolderVersion
export statisticsVersion
export infosVersion
export receiptVersion
export uiVersion
export telemetryVersion

echo "Running docker-compose"
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up &
```

All internal commands (docker images) works individually

here is the docker-compose.yml in /app :

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  hardware:
    privileged: true
    image: service-hardware-image:$hardwareVersion
    container_name: hardware
    ports:
      - 6001:6000
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - data:/data

  hotfolder:
    image: service-hotfolder-image:$hotfolderVersion
    container_name: hotfolder
    ports:
      - 6003:6000
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - data:/data

  statistics:
    image: service-statistics-image:$statisticsVersion
    container_name: statistics
    ports:
      - 6004:6000
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - data:/data

  receipt:
    privileged: true
    image: service-receipt-image:$receiptVersion
    container_name: receipt
    ports:
      - 6005:6000
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - data:/data

  payment:
    privileged: true
    image: service-payment-image:$paymentVersion
    container_name: payment
    ports:
      - 6002:6000
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - data:/data

  telemetry:
    privileged: true
    image: service-telemetry-image:$telemetryVersion
    container_name: telemetry
    ports:
      - 6006:6000
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - data:/data

  ui:
    image: service-ui-image:$uiVersion
    container_name: ui
    environment:
      - SystemSettings__IsSimulator=false
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - data:/data
      - wwwrootimages:/app/wwwroot/images

networks:
    my-network:
      external:
        name: my-network

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/data'
  wwwrootimages:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/data/configuration/services/ui/images'
```

Also i should mention that this script works on other computers, it's just mine which is having issues

Comment: Can you share any relevant `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml`? It's hard to tell anything without your setup.

Comment: I added precisions

Comment: What are the images for `service-hardware-image` etc.? It's still not possible to diagnose yet.

Comment: Those are images from a project but there are on my computer : 
```docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" | grep "hardware" | cut -d' ' -f2``` return "1.0.0" and i checked, they are correctly named and taged
They are dotnet projects but i'm not sure they are relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that your command

```
statisticsVersion=$(docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" | grep "statistics" | cut -d' ' -f2)
```

does not return newline special character.
It does not make sense to have this newline character encoded `%0A` in the url `/v1.30/images/service-statistics-image:1.0.0%0A0/json`

Comment: Indeed, i had another image named "statistics" and taged with :0
I have other errors but at least i'm moving forward, thx.